# Maven/Eclipse with Vagrant

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, vagrant

I'm trying to convert a Java project which builds in Maven (and Gradle and Ant... it's complicated unfortunately) to use Vagrant. I already have most of the machine provisioned with Puppet, and it's awesome having a portable, destructible development environment and not having to install and configure all of this software on my own personal machines.

The problem I'm currently facing is this: how will I resolve my classpath in Eclipse? My build tools (Maven, Gradle, Ant) are installed on the Vagrant box, and they download archives to the local machine in `/home/vagrant/.m2` etc.

Here's what I *can* do fairly easily over the Vagrant machine:

1. *Build* my entire software project using the Ant, Maven, and Gradle build
   tools installed on the Vagrant machine.
2. *Run* my entire software project on my application servers installed on the Vagrant machine.
3. *Access* and interact with the application servers over a forwarded HTTP port.

Here's what I'm sorely missing:

1. *Develop* using Eclipse and using the Maven/Gradle classpath which exists inside of the Vagrant VM.
2. *Debug/Run* using Eclipse, starting the applications inside of the Vagrant container to make use of that environment and not my host machine's environment.

Are there Eclipse plugins which will allow me to use a remote classpath with m2eclipse? Can I run/debug Java executables remotely on the Vagrant machine?

If "the bottom line™" is that I simply *must* have Maven and Gradle installed on my local machine in addition to the Vagrant box, then it is what it is; otherwise, I'd really prefer to keep my local machine as lightweight as possible.

## The Goal

Run my entire software development cycle inside of a Vagrant machine, making Eclipse *the only* dependency on my local machine.

Comment: Have you tried any remoting software to run eclipse on the vagrant machine?

Comment: You are trying to extend your dev environment across 2 machine, I don't understand motive behind this ? we have similar setup where we use cloud virtulization tool (like vagrant) to test the app and to deploy it, but not for directly running from eclipse

Comment: @JigarJoshi The goal is to have my local machine _only_ require Eclipse, period. I don't have time to manually provision all of these different build tools, environment configuration, services, etc. on each local machine that I own, hence - Vagrant.

Comment: @JoshBerry I'm not sure what you're referring to. Do you mean running Eclipse _inside_ of Vagrant using X forwarding?

Comment: why not use symbolic links?
1. create a folder on you local machine $USER/.m2
2. create a link from you vagrant project (proj/m2 -> $USER/.m2)
3. in Vagrantfile link /home/vagrant/.m2 to /vagrant/m2
this way your local eclipse will find .m2 automatically and you'll be able to compile from both inside and outside (assuming you have pom.xml/build.gradle/etc., and the relevant eclipse plugin). also, you won't need to download the whole set of libraries after every "vagrant destroy"

Comment: I did mean to run eclipse inside of Vagrant.  Alternatively, you can look into running docker containers on your local machine.  Though... I have zero experience with that. :(

Comment: You will also require a JVM on your local machine

Answer (score 1):

In your Vagrantfile you can declare a shared folder for you host and guest.  /home/vagrant/.m2/repository on the guest you could link to an extension folder, for the jvm or Eclipse if it supports a lib/ext.